# JQSuite JQGrid XDate displays as a long integer

Tags: c#, asp.net, jqgrid-asp.net, jqchart

I'm using the ASP.NET Webforms version of JQSuite with JQChart as part of it.

My charts are all being populated from codebehind and so far are working as expected, however I've followed the example here: http://www.trirand.net/examples/chart/line/timedateirregularintervals/default.aspx to use the `XDate` property.

In code behind this wants a `DateTime?` value, which is no problem, as I just parse the date from my SQL server into a datetime using `DateTime.Parse` - however as an example:

```
2013-11-18 displays as 1384732800000
```

How do I get it to display as 2013-11-18, or 18-11-2013?

I found this: [Displaying Dates Correctly for JQSuite JQChart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363625/displaying-dates-correctly-for-jqsuite-jqchart) but doesn't really answer it given I'm passing a valid `DateTime` type to the `ChartPoint` object.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, *slaps forehead* so simple

```
ChartXAxisSettings x = new ChartXAxisSettings();
x.Type = ChartAxisType.DateTime;
```